# getting old value of scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

Is it possible somehow to get old value of scope property? I have such code with comment inside:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    // here I need to get old value of some scope property, for example $scope.userInfo;
}, function() {
    $scope.callSomeFunction();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's in the second function - so to watch `userInfo`

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.userInfo;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(oldValue);
    $scope.callSomeFunction();
}, true);
```

Comment: @pavel06081991 -- The first function tells the watcher what to watch... why would you need it there?

Comment: I have to watch one scope object, If it changes by reference or by value I have to call my function. But I have to use $watch two times to do this. First time without third param of $watch function to watch by reference and second time with third param to watch by value. It is bad, so I want to use only one $watch and get old and new value of my object to compare them by myself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about the property your watch is watching, than you simply get it in the callback function.

```
$scope.$watch('property', function(newValue, oldValue) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way

```
$scope.$watch('userInfo', function(newValue, oldValue) {    
return oldValue;    
})
```